# How to use Zend Framework 1.8 unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework

In Zend Framework 1.8, using Zend_Tool, the framework now generates controllers, actions, etc. automatically.

What it does is that it also creates a tests directory when creating a project.

```
quickstart
|-- application
|   |-- Bootstrap.php
|   |-- configs
|   |   `-- application.ini
|   |-- controllers
|   |   |-- ErrorController.php
|   |   `-- IndexController.php
|   |-- models
|   `-- views
|       |-- helpers
|       `-- scripts
|           |-- error
|           |   `-- error.phtml
|           `-- index
|               `-- index.phtml
|-- library
|-- public
|   `-- index.php
    `-- tests
|-- application
|   `-- bootstrap.php
|-- library
|   `-- bootstrap.php
    `-- phpunit.xml
```

So what does it do? How do I actually use it?
I am reading about unit-testing and hopefully this will help understand it more.

Thanks,
Wenbert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the test folder manually. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-with-the-zend-framework-with-zend_test-and-phpunit/2009/06/).